# Connect to Mongo Router inside Docker container from remote host

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-network, mongo-shell

I have an EC2 instance in AWS with a `mongo` docker container that init a `mongo router` such as :

```
docker run --network mongo-net -p 27051:27017 --expose=27017 -d --name=mongos51 mongo mongos --port 27017 --configdb configserver/configserver41:27017,configserver42:27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

I have opened my SG in AWS to allow any connections and i can reach the public IP on the port 27051 without problems.

My container is in a `bidge` docker network to allow all of my mongo instances to communicate.

However, if i try to connect to the `mongo shell` like :

```
mongosh mongodb://public_ip:27051
```

I have the error `Connection refused` instantly. Same if i try to open the mongoshell from inside the container with :

```
docker exec -it mongos51 bash -c "echo 'sh.addShard(\"shard1/mongodb11\")' | mongosh "
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6149ed68def89bc1907c8988
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

I have the same error if i use the private IP instead of `127.0.0.1`.

What i am missing here ?

Comment: is it a typo `27052`, port exposed is `27051`

Comment: sorry my bad, i actually have 2 containers with ports 27052 and 27051 like this and both don't work unfortunately. Both are publicly available too an reachable : 
```nc -vnzu public_ip 27052
Connection to public_ip port 27052 [udp/*] succeeded!```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation try to connect like this :

```
mongosh --host public_ip --port 27051
```

It work for me when I follow these [steps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).